# What are the New Method to Deserialize JSON Object into DataSet in C#?

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

Here is My Code Sample:

```
string json = "[{Vehicle:BMW With Ethiraj,Date:30 Jul 2013 09:24 AM,Location:Hauz Khas Enclave New Delhi Delhi India, Speed:42}]";
```

> by custom method

DataTable dt = JsonStringToDataTable(json);

> by Newtonsoft method

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

> JsonStringToDataTable method:-

```
public DataTable JsonStringToDataTable(string jsonString)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string[] jsonStringArray = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
            List<string> ColumnsName = new List<string>();
            foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
            {
                string[] jsonStringData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                foreach (string ColumnsNameData in jsonStringData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(",");
                        string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                        if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
                        {
                            ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", ColumnsNameData));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            foreach (string AddColumnName in ColumnsName)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(AddColumnName);
            }
            foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
            {
                string[] RowData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (string rowData in RowData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                        string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                        string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                        nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(nr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

> but above both method are throw error

1. JsonStringToDataTable model error --> Additional information: Error Parsing Column Name : Vehicle:BMW With Ethiraj
2. JSON Model error -- > Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: B. Path '[0].Vehicle', line 1, position 10.

Why i'm trying this JSON to Dataset means need to export excel, pdf, etc 
by Jquery client side Jquery ajax method we send JSON data and process at Web-method without depend c# code as well as i tried excel export using jquery method but which is not support Internet Explorer so thats why i try to do this DeserializeObject, so anybody have different idea pls share

Comment: The example input you have posted here is not valid JSON. I would use a regular json parser and then transform that result into a DataTable. Seems safer than trying to build your own custom parser.

Comment: okay good post your samples

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error with the Newtonsoft method because the `json` string is not in correct format. You should put the values within single/double quotes in that json string after which your sample `json` would look something like this:

```
string json = "{\"arr\":[{\"Vehicle\":\"BMW With Ethiraj\",\"Date\":\"30 Jul 2013 09:24 AM\",\"Location\":\"Hauz Khas Enclave New Delhi Delhi India\", \"Speed\":\"42\"}]}";
```

Thereafter, use the Newtonsoft method in the below way:

```
DataSet ds = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
```

Comment: same error -- > Additional information: Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object. Path '[0].Vehicle', line 1, position 12.

Comment: did u modify the json string to include single/double quotes in it?

Comment: yes i got same error -- > string json = "[{\'Vehicle\':\'BMW With Ethiraj\',\'Date\':\'30 Jul 2013 09:24 AM\',\'Location\':\'Hauz Khas Enclave New Delhi Delhi India\', \'Speed\':\'42\'}]";

Comment: That is because the json string array does not have a key for the array. Try with this string - `string json = "{\'ds\':[{\'Vehicle\':\'BMW With Ethiraj\',\'Date\':\'30 Jul 2013 09:24 AM\',\'Location\':\'Hauz Khas Enclave New Delhi Delhi India\', \'Speed\':\'42\'}]}";`